# Two players place red and blue stones on a chessboard. The goal is to make a rectangle with all red or all blue corners. Who wins?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Imagine a game played on a 3-by-7 chessboard. There are two players in this game - one with red stones and one with blue stones. The goal of the game is to make a rectangle with vertices all of your own color. The corners do not need to be connected by solid lines of stones. For example, using chess notation, if a player has red stones on a1, b1, a6, and b6, then they win the game.

Does a winning strategy for either player exist? If it does, what is it? It is known that this game cannot end in a draw - every 2-coloring of a $3\times 7$ lattice grid is guaranteed to contain a rectangle with vertices of the same color.

Additionally, this can be generalized to $n$ players with different colors on an $(n+1)\times (\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}+1)$ board. Who wins in these variations?

Comment: Hints: Prove that this is a finite combinatorial game that must end with a winner. Then prove that the first player has a winning strategy by stealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice Question!
[Zeremelo's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%27s_theorem_(game_theory)) says that in any finite two player perfect information game that cannot end in a draw one of the two players must have a winning strategy. So, yes your statement that there does not exist a draw, implies that one of the two players has a winning strategy.

I believe this game can be thought of as a [hypergraph game](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/iii/Hypergraph_Games.pdf). Therefore, the argument of [strategy stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument) implies that Player 1 has the winning strategy.

Unfortunately, Idon't know what the wining strategy is, but Player 1 certainly has it.